# When can I buy stuff from Ravio?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I asked a question about the rewards for picking up the Maiamai babies, and in a comment someone mentioned that I could only upgrade things I had bought from Ravio.  As far as I can see, he will only rent stuff to me at the moment, not let me buy it to keep. When or how does this change? Do I have to do something specific?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to beat both the Tower of Hera and The House of Gales and get all three Pendants: 
**Green/Courage from Zelda, Blue/Wisdom from Gales, Red/Power from Hera**.

Once you have them, then just visit Ravio again.

Comment: As I just discovered, this visit has to be independent of the times you end up there when you die, which is why it hadn't popped for me yet.